# The addressing mode can write like this?

Tags: assembly, addressing-mode

I want use cmp instruction, Whether to set up the following syntax in assembly language?
example:

```
cmp [temp + si],[temp + si+1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do (exactly) this. For almost any instruction on an Intel x86, one of the operands must be a register.

There is an exception to that: `cmpsb` compares `[ds:si]` to `[es:di]` (or, in 32-bit mode, `[ds:esi]` to `[es:edi]`, or in 64-bit mode, uses `rsi` and `rdi`).

If you want to use `si` to point to both operands, however, you'll need to load some other register, then compare:

```
mov al, [temp+si]
cmp al, [temp+si+1]
```

Another possibility is to load from `[si]`, and increment `si`:

```
lodsb          ;roughly equivalent to mov al, [si] / inc si
cmp al, [si]
```

Since this is only able to use `si`, not `temp+si`, you'd need to add those together before using this. This is a little shorter, but (at least theoretically) slower on most current processors.  To regain the speed, you could also use the more primitive instructions:

```
mov al, [si+temp]
inc si
cmp al, [si+temp]
```

Or, since you're using `+temp` for both instructions, you might gain a little by doing that addition ahead of time:

```
add si, temp
mov al, [si]
inc si
cmp al, [si]
```

One thing to keep in mind though: since you're working with data in memory, this may not make any real difference in speed -- if you do much with memory, the bandwidth to memory is often (usually?) the bottleneck, so optimizing execution of the instructions on the processor itself makes little difference.

Comment: Assuming it's x86, which the OP doesn't specify.